# NS timer with view transition multiple times

Tags: ios, nstimer, uistoryboardsegue

i found out how to do this from a youtube video on this web page http://x-code-tutorials.com/2013/06/19/nstimer-trigger-uiviewcontroller-transition/ .
however i wish to use this multiple times with different view controllers but i am not quite sure how to do it .you can also download the project from that link . i have been trying to work it out but i simply can't . if possible could you display the whole code in your answer so i could just copy and paste it . i would really appreciate if you could help me . thank you in advance .

here is the image of the view controller.m and the errors . please help me asap.https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FVaC.png

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to add this code till your last view :

On every 
**ViewController.h** File

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
        NSTimer *transitionTimer;
}
```

And in 
    **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startTimerMethod];
}

- (void) startTimerMethod {
    transitionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) transitionView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewTransition" sender:self];
}
```

just change Segue Identifier with change of your view.

Comment: In the view controller.m it says duplicate declaration of method viewDidAppear and startTimerMethod . Is there any way to correct this

Comment: i have added a screen shot of the Xcode view controller.m above

Comment: you declare that two methods two times ,just remove it.
What you have to do is to add ViewController, and add that two method in it.

Comment: I still don't understand do I just copy and paste it below . Can you explain or write it down exactly what I am suppoesed so I can copy and paste it please . I'm still learning sorry .